# Javascript stopped working after combination

Tags: javascript

Well I had lots of scripts so what I did is that I combined all of them into one script file, which contains files like Jquery library too.
But now the problem is that it has stopped working, I don't know why did this happen.

What I did is that I took every script copied and pasted it and then I gave some space under it by pressing enter a few times and then I used to paste other script, I was told this was the method to combine scripts but now the scripts don't work.
Here is the link to combined scripts http://files.cryoffalcon.com/bloghuts/uncompressed/BlogHuts%20UNCOMPRESSED.js

And the link to a live example is http://bloghutsbeta.blogspot.com/

ANSWER/SOLUTION:

Earlier I was using an older version of Jquery I think 1.5 now I changed it to latest 1.7 and that was the reason that everything stopped working. It had nothing to do with combination. I am using all scripts combined and everything is working fine But why is older version better than New that is a new question for me

Comment: i don't think it's a good idea to combine 3rd party js-files with your own! what is the gain in that?

Comment: Well I didn't combined third part files except for Jquery. And the gain is that see my script file it got lots of script in it. Before they were combined they were liked 15 script files so you can understand it was a mess

Comment: minus one. you are making 1+1=3

Comment: @rowhunter well, don't do that, for a start. Then take care of the charset somehow, there seem to be some weird chars. Keep single parts seperat and if it still not works -- supply some information. more than _it does not work_

Comment: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/ - JQuery 1.6 release notes.  Apparently they broke a few things on the way through.  Likely this happened because you were using one or more of them.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd suggest you move the jquery library links out to the main page.  Have one file for all of your javascript, and include the other stuff on separate lines.

Whether or not you do that, though, your problem is almost certainly some sort of unclosed bracket or semicolon missing or something similar.  Javascript often reacts to stuf like that by throwing its hands up in the air and giving up.  The way to fix it is to go through your file and pick a function that is not currently working, but that is easy to test for functionality.  Then comment out everything else, and test to see if the function works.  If not, fix the function until it does work.  Then, one piece at a time, uncomment each of the other blocks, again testing to see if the initial function works.  If uncommenting a block causes the thing to stop working, then that's the block that you need to fix.  Depending on how long your blocks are, you may need to do this in tiers

Answer (score 0):

First, don't do that with jQuery, ever. You're almost always better off pointing your script src to a [public CDN](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery) somewhere.

Second, what you're trying to do is very brittle, and probably not worth troubleshooting. If you have that many JS files, you really need to use a module library (I like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)) to give your project some structure and make it more manageable. Most libraries like this will include some sort of utility to combine and minifi your scripts safely.

This will take some work on your part to get things setup, but it should prove well worth it in the long run!